# Why function __pud_alloc() is undefined in kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm a beginner at Linux Kernel. Now I'm trying to write a module to set page table by myself.

My computer is x86 and the kernel version is 5.4.0.

First I use the kernel parameter `memmap` to reserve some memory, then I try to set page table for the reserved memory.

I use `pud_alloc` in my code and `include <linux/mm.h>`, but then I see this error:

```
ERROR: "__pud_alloc" [/root/sun_fs/sunfs.ko] undefined!
ERROR: "init_mm" [/root/sun_fs/sunfs.ko] undefined!
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:94: __modpost] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1670: modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-65-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:9: default] Error 2
```

Both `__pud_alloc` and `init_mm` are undefined.

I find `__pud_alloc` is declared in `/include/linux/mm.h` and defined in `mm/memory.c`. But why I can't use it?

Do I have another way to set page table manually?

Comment: Soo what about that `#ifndef __PAGETABLE_PUD_FOLDED` around it? Also, I see no `EXPORT_SYMBOL`.

Comment: "I'm trying to write a module to set page table by myself." - Operating with the page tables is not a native task for a kernel **module**. Either do that work in the kernel core, or choose another task for your toy module.

Comment: @KamilCuk  Yes, I guess it is because there is no `EXPORT_SYMBOL` that caused this problem. And I checked before, pud is not folded in my system.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you~, Actually, I want my module to use some memory that OS will not use, so I figure out this way. Do I have another way to achieve this?

Comment: "I want my module to use some memory that OS will not use" - Google (or use another search engine) for "linux kernel reserve memory".